# Can we use apache poi jars in soapui?

Tags: java, rest, soap, soapui

Is it possible to use all the jars that are used in java coding to run in soapui. if yes where to import the jars and how to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the java libraries in SoapUI.

All you need to do is to copy the libraries under *SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext* directory and restart the SoapUI tool.

Now you should be able to use them in `Groovy Script` test step, just like how we use in java.

For more details see [here](http://rupertanderson.com/blog/1-how-to-develop-add-and-use-a-custom-groovy-library-in-soapui/)

Comment: The Links mentioned is not working ,its throwing the page not found error.